# Giving Access to every file on computer

Tags: file, c#-4.0, search, access-denied, documents

I keep receiving the No access to Documents and Settings issue. I've tried coding it to where certain flags on the directories will stop this, but I then do not get all the folders on the computer..... My plan is to use the Directory.GetFiles() method once I have all of the folders in a list. However, all I get is the Drive names.... Any ideas?

I use this to check if i can use the directory:

```
    public static bool IsEmptyDirectory(string path)
    {
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) != 0)
        {
            return true;//Not allowed to read, errors out
        }//if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) != 0)
        else if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != 0)
        {
            return true;//Not allowed to read, errors out
        }//else if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != 0)
        else if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) != 0)
        {
            return true;//Not allowed to read, errors out
        }//else if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.System) != 0)
        else
        {
            return false;//Should be safe to read
        }//else
    }//public static bool IsEmptyDirectory(string path)
```

Here is what happens on Button Click:
            List FileList = new List();
            string Directory = "";

```
        foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            Directory = drive.Name;
            SearchDir(ref FileList, Directory);
        }//foreach (var drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())

        foreach (string folderfound in FileList)
        {
            lstDupePics.Items.Add(folderfound);
        }
```

Here is the SearchDir method:

```
    public void SearchDir(ref List<string> FileList, string directory)
    {
        FileList.Add(directory);

        if (!clsFunctions.IsEmptyDirectory(directory))
        {
            string[] sfolderList = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);

            foreach (string sfolder in sfolderList)
            {
                SearchDir(ref FileList, sfolder);
            }
        }
    }
```

Maybe I'm just over complicating this......